# fabric.js: Always visible controls

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for image manipulation and it works great, but I need the controls to be always visible even when I click outside the object/image.

By default they are visible only when you click the objec/image, if you click outside of it the controls disappear.

Is it possibile to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Recently i go through the same scenario and i make it solved by using a `setActiveObject()` property: 
`canvas.setActiveObject(fabricObject)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in FabricJS, to achieve this at the moment.

However, here is a workaround *(function)* , which will simulate this functionality ...

```
function showControls(...objs) {
   objs.forEach(obj => {
      obj.set('active', true);
      canvas.renderAll();
      canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
         obj.set('active', true);
      });
   })
}
```

after adding the image object on the canvas, call the above function along with passing the image object as a parameter, that you wish to show controls for.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
// add rectangle (for demo purposes only)
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
   top: 100,
   left: 290,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: '#07C',
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center',
   transparentCorners: false
});
canvas.add(rect);
// add image (for demo purposes only)
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg', function(img) {
   img.set({
      top: 100,
      left: 110,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      transparentCorners: false
   })
   canvas.add(img);
   showControls(img); // pass an object that you wish to show controls for
});

// always show controls (multi-object support)
function showControls(...objs) {
   objs.forEach(obj => {
      obj.set('active', true);
      canvas.renderAll();
      canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
         obj.set('active', true);
      });
   })
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer, that works great.

Comment: The above code is not working when I use cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js

Answer (score 1):

not perfect, but a start

```js
// fabricjs object - always show controls

//fabric.Object.prototype.render = (function (render) {
fabric.Image.prototype.render = (function (render) {
    return function (ctx) {
        render.apply(this, arguments)

        // show controls
        // but most controls are not usable
        // until you activate [click] the object
        this._renderControls(ctx)

        // activate this object
        // to make all controls usable
        // only one active object per canvas
        // when another object is active
        // the controls become not usable
        if (!this.canvas._activeObject)
            this.canvas._activeObject = this
    }
//})(fabric.Object.prototype.render)
})(fabric.Image.prototype.render)



// fabricjs object - activate on mouseover
// this is just a quick hack
// to make controls always usable

//fabric.Object.prototype.initialize = (function (initialize) {
fabric.Image.prototype.initialize = (function (initialize) {
    return function () {
        initialize.apply(this, arguments)

        this.on('mouseover',
        function(event) {
            this.canvas.setActiveObject(this)
            this.canvas.renderAll() // TODO cheaper?
        })
    }
//})(fabric.Object.prototype.initialize)
})(fabric.Image.prototype.initialize)
```